# Twilio sms question

Tags: php, twilio

Uptill now I have been using Twilio for phone calls. Now I want to be able to have a network monitoring tool that texts when there is a problem to a number. I would like to make it so that when twilio receives the text it will execute the script that I have put into its URL...I really don't know how to get started with sms it seems very hard and complicated as compared to phone calls...Any help on the sms is greatly appreciated to get me started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've already figured Twilio voice calls, you'll find SMS easier once you figure out what they're doing. Which is essentially:

1. Carrier delivers an SMS to Twilio for a number you're renting from them.
2. Twilio makes an HTTP POST or GET (you choose) to the URL you setup in their web admin. The content of the text message will be a parameter in there.
3. You do whatever you want with the POST or GET, returning a [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) if you want an SMS reply sent or nothing if not.

Note, Twilio can't execute a script for you, unless it's TwiML, in which case you're just returning TwiML as the response to the HTTP call from #3. So if you want to *do* something in response to an SMS, you'll need build that something into the logic that handles the URL you've given Twilio. If you're still lost a bit, tell us about how you're trying to do this, e.g., you've a Rails app, a PHP website, or just a Bash script you want to run and nothing else yet...

Comment: But what would I need to do if I want the reply to be Twilio making a call to a number specified once it receives a text from someone?

I am using service desk plus, that network monitoring tool can send texts, I want to make it so that network monitoring tool will sms to twilio's number, and then Twilio will run the script its holding at web admin which tells Twilio to call a specific number.

Comment: In that case, the TwiML script telling Twilio to make the voice call will be what you want to return in response to #2 above, see http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/your_response

Comment: Disregard that last comment of mine--not very well thought through. You'll need to start the voice call by making a request to their REST API. See my answer to your follow-on question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not avoid Twilio and have your network monitoring tool execute the script itself?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the whole idea of using Twilio to run the script is so that a call can be made to someone with the script so that the script can handle the call the way its suppose to. The network monitoring tool I am using is service desk plus, it doesnt have the Say verbs or anything that I know of to read things to the caller it calls.