# Twilio's receive sms and send a call..

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to do this but it is not working....I was trying to text to my sandbox sms at Twilio so once twilio receive's that sms it would execute a script that should dial a number. This is not working as I get no error so I am assuming the only place where the Dial verb works is in the phone section of Twilio and not the sms part. Any help?

I want the sms to be a trigger that starts up a script which uses Twilio's dial verb to call people and give a message then hang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <Dial> verb is a top level one, so it should be a child of <Response>, i.e., not <Sms>. That said, Twilio's documentation strongly implies putting <Dial> in the <Response> for an SMS callback won't work; <Dial> is supposed to connect a *current caller* to another party. So, if this isn't working, you'll hit their REST API to [initiate the call](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making_calls); you can POST the TwiML script with the message to speak and the instruction to then hang up.

*Note this contradicts my first reply to your comment on [your other Twilio question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851082/twilio-sms-question/6851617#6851617), my apologies for that.*